# Enable Sign in with Twitter - Callback URLs

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Enable Sign in with Twitter[![Callback URLs][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkZPx.pngEnable Sign in with Twitter

What I need to put in Callback URLs to allow me to Enable Sign in with Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the internet accessible URL where your web app is running and will receive the response and OAuth tokens from the sign in flow.

Comment: I'm running the web app on my pc.

Comment: It will need an internet URL.